# GNU radio:error in running modtool for making new modules

Tags: c++, gnuradio

hi i am trying to add new blocks in gnuradio .  I tried to follow the the procedure mentioned  in gnuradio website

```
http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/OutOfTreeModules?version=24
```

but when in terminal window i write "gr_modtool newmod howto"
it gives following error

```
File "/usr/local/bin/gr_modtool", line 41, in <module>
    main()
File "/usr/local/bin/gr_modtool", line 36, in main
  modtool.setup()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/modtool/modtool_newmod.py",   line   70, in setup

  self._srcdir = gr.prefs().get_string('modtool', 'newmod_path', options.srcdir)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/gr/gnuradio_core_general.py", line 18953, in get_string

return _gnuradio_core_general.gr_prefs_get_string(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

TypeError: in method 'gr_prefs_get_string', argument 4 of type 'std::string const'

please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To create your own modules in GNU Radio Companion using the gr_modtool try this:

```
$ gr_modtool newmod

Name of the new module: myPlugin
```

To add processing blocks to your newly created module use:

```
../gr-myPlugin$ gr_modtool add
```

You can choose if you want a cpp or python block by adding the "-l" specificier:

```
../gr-myPlugin$ gr_modtool add -l python
```

More info:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2013-03/msg00216.html